# Magento 2: How to display Category Image at top of the page after breadcrumbs

Tags: magento2, category, image, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to display category image after bread crumbs. Is that possible to display after bread crumbs? If possible please let me know how can i do that. Here is the screenshot of my website.

[image: Screenshot of my website]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **move element** of xml to display category image at top of the page. 
Navigate to

> Magento_Catalog/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

Put this code before body end

```
<move element="category.image" destination="columns.top" before="-" />
```

Comment: That block is already in the columns.top container. Here I have added the custom module called( Subcategory master ) so that the module is displaying above the ' columns.top ' container. I would like to display the category image above custom module.

Comment: If you have added custom module then you have to move the position of your custom block.

Comment: I can understand  what you have said. but i can't find any layout file in the custom module, Can i create layout file in the module? if can please give me any reference for creating the layout file. Tq